# Non-identically distributed Bernoulli trials

Tags: probability, probability-theory

It is well-known that, if I want to estimate the bias of a coin $p$ to within additive accuracy $\epsilon$, I'll have to flip the coin approximately $1/\epsilon^2$ times.

What if instead I have a fixed $\alpha > 0$ and sequence of independent Bernoulli random variables $X_t$ such that $\Pr[X_t = 1] = \cos^2(t\alpha)$ and I want to estimate $\alpha$.  Does a similar bound apply?